# How can I check why my electron processes are getting killed by Windows?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app deployed on Windows 10 systems with customers. My app has 3 processes running in the background. However, off and on, the processes seem to get killed (I am assuming by the OS).

The app is installed under the user directory.

I have checked into Windows Event loggers, and I do find logs for my app. Some of the logs seem to be about Office 16 Click-to-run Licensing component.

> Product: Office 16 Click-to-Run Licensing Component. The file >c:\Windows\system32\msvcp140.dll is being used by the following process: >Name: nGage , Id 14360.

I am wondering if Windows would kill my process if it is trying to upgrade Office 16 or some such.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Arun

Comment: are you using an `uncaughException` handler to log messages somewhere, or [`crashReporter`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/crash-reporter)

Comment: I am logging messages to log files on the user machine, but not using a crashReporter or uncaughtException handler. Thanks, I shall try that first.

Comment: How did u find the events in event viewer. What was the eventid or query used. Where did u check ?( security/Software/Application )